# next and previous category name and link parent only wordpress in archive page

Tags: pagination, archives, archive-template

**how get next and previous category name and link parent only wordpress in archive page**
I tried a lot but worked by fetching an ID and adding 1 or losing 1
But this is causing my mistakes

Comment: What exactly did you try? Could you [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/292614/edit) using the [`edit` link above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/292614/edit) and add in any code or things that you've attempted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_categories()` to grab details about all of the categories that exist in the database - that way you know which IDs are active categories and which are not. Just so you are aware, by default, `get_categories()` will only return categories that contain at least 1 post. You can force empty categories to show by adding `'hide_empty' => true`.

```
<?php
// identify the current category
$category = get_queried_object();
$categoryId = $category->term_id;
// get all the categories
$allCategories = get_categories(array(
    'orderby' => 'id', // order them by their ID
    'order' => 'ASC', // counting up
    'parent' => 0)); // only if it's a top-level category
// save first and last IDs, so we only loop through existing categories
$firstId = $allCategories[0]->id;
$lastCategory = end(array_values($allCategories));
$lastId = $lastCategory->id;
// loop to find Next Category - start 1 higher than current ID
for($i = ($categoryID + 1); $i <= $lastId; $i++) {
    if(isset($allCategories[$i])) {
        $nextCategoryLink = sprintf(
            // set up a link
            '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
            // put the URL into href=""
            esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
            // use category name as link text
            $category->name
        );
        // exit the loop so we only have 1 Next
        break;
    }
}
// loop backwards to find Previous - start 1 lower than current ID
for($i = ($categoryId - 1); $i >= $firstId; $i--) {
    if(isset($allCategories[$i])) {
        $prevCategoryLink = sprintf(
            // set up a link
            '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
            // put the URL into href=""
            esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
            // use category name as link text
            $category->name
        );
        // exit the loop so we only have 1 Previous
        break;
    }
}
// now, out put the links
// note that if the current category is the first, it won't have "prev"
// and if the current category is the last, it won't have "next"
if(!empty($prevCategoryLink)) { echo $prevCategoryLink; }
if(!empty($nextCategoryLink)) { echo $nextCategoryLink; }
?>
```

Hopefully the comments will guide you through what each step is doing.

Comment: Does not work I have the name of the existing Category
But I want the next Category and the previous Category

Comment: How specifically did this not work? Where did you place the code?

Comment: in archive page themes

Comment: Did it show up at all, or was there an error? Perhaps in your theme there is a `category.php` you need to modify rather than `archive.php`.